# C++ Streams Should Not create New Line

Tags: c++, iostream

i try to make program that write timestamp to file with c++ here is my code :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("time.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
    string savetime;
    for(;;){
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        savetime=asctime(localtime(&t));
        cout<<savetime;
        outfile << savetime << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    
}
```

result of this code is

```
Sun Dec 06 01:28:17 2020

Sun Dec 06 01:28:18 2020

Sun Dec 06 01:28:19 2020

Sun Dec 06 01:28:20 2020
```

it has new line every lines. i have try to remove `endl` at  `outfile << savetime << endl;` to remove new lines but file wont save new timestamp. my goal is to make output like this

```
Sun Dec 06 01:28:17 2020
Sun Dec 06 01:28:18 2020
Sun Dec 06 01:28:19 2020
Sun Dec 06 01:28:20 2020
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Quoting [cppreference's documentation page for `asctime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime): *Converts given calendar time std::tm to a textual representation of the following fixed 25-character form: `Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy\n`* Note the `\n` on the end of the format string. [Use `std::strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead. You get to control all of the formatting.

Comment: An alternative is [C++20's new date utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) or [Howard Hinnant's data library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) if C++20 isn't available to you yet.

Comment: You can use `std::flush` instead of `std::endl` to write your text to the file immediately without writing a newline. When you remove the endl, you see no output until the stream is flushed. It will flush if you: use `std::endl`, `std::flush`, call `outfile.close()` or allow the fstream to be destroyed at the end of the scope, by terminating the loop. This might let you get what you want, without altering your code in any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("time.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
    char savetime[100];
    for(;;){
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        strftime(savetime, sizeof(savetime), "%A %c", localtime(&t));
        cout<<savetime;
        outfile << savetime<<endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

thanks to user4581301

from `savetime=asctime(localtime(&t));` to `strftime(savetime, sizeof(savetime), "%A %c", localtime(&t));`

Comment: Good answer, but you want `%a` instead of `%A` to duplicate the abbreviated day names displayed by `asctime`